# SWIFT: IMDF Indoor Map enable 3D effect instead of flat surface

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, imdf

I am playing around with [IMDF](https://register.apple.com/resources/indoor/Apple-Indoor-Maps-Guidelines.pdf) from the new [Apple Indoor Maps Program](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/241/).
However I am experimenting with 3D effect of the building (walls etc.).
With official maps app we can achieve this effect easily by panning the camera in an angle between 89° and 45° like so:

[image: Airport Indoor Maps]

Now I tried to achieve this by enabling pitch gesture `self.mapView.isPitchEnabled = true` to the [example app for IMDF from apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/displaying_an_indoor_map) but the result is only a flat surface.

[image: pitch enabled]

Now I tried to enable buildings `self.mapView.showsBuildings = true`, because I thought enabling buildings could trigger some function to render IMDF-Data to 3D, but the result was disappointing.

[image: buildings enabled]

As we can see the IMDF-Data renders only some kind of overlay to the map.
Looking to the documentation of IMDF, airport indoor maps are also done with IMDF, so where is the trick?
Is it even possible to get the 3D-effect as a private developer?

**Update 29.06.2020:**

Tried at 08.06.2020 to ask an apple developer with the specific email for IMDF-questions provided by apple. [imdfquestions@apple.com](http://mailto:imdfquestions@apple.com). No answer so far.
Asked the same question at the apple developer forum. No answer either.

Comment: I'm starting to think this effect is currently private and custom made by Apple for some locations and there's no APIs from Apple to achieve this. I hope I'm wrong because I think it looks cool and significant enough for Apple to not showcase in their announcement if it was public for developers.